# Pyinstaller Failed o pack Python Program into executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to make my python program executable using pyinistaller but for some reason in keep getting the same error in the command prompt:

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 462, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 962, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 787, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\ksabitova\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-numpy.core.py", line 29, in <module>
    pkg_base, pkg_dir = get_package_paths('numpy.core')
  File "C:\Users\ksabitova\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 537, in get_package_paths
    file_attr = get_module_file_attribute(package)
  File "C:\Users\ksabitova\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 339, in get_module_file_attribute
    raise ImportError
ImportError
```

Comment: It seems like a module cannot be found / imported. It is hard to check which one based on just the error here, it might be numpy but I am not sure.

Comment: it showed me matplotlib before, i uninstalled matplib and installed it again, and now it just shows ImportError

Comment: some modules you have to add manually to config file. You should check in Google if someone had problem with Numpy in pyinstaller - maybe someone already resolved this problem.